# Snowflake data steward discovery based on role hierarchy

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake follows the [role-based access control (RBAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) paradigm. Best practice for RBAC is, to have functional and access roles managing either user and clients or access privileges. This creates in worst-case a variety of roles that inherits permissions from and to each other. By nature, one can easily lose sight.

In snowflake, grants to roles and users are stored in `ACCESS_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES` and `ACCESS_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS`. What is a proper approach to identify the data stewards/owner of a role automatically (if not labeled explicitly in a 3rd party tooling)?

Options I thought of:

- recursive lookup of `OWNERSHIP` privileges of roles of roles (will generate a lot of false positives)
- recursive discovery of a service account that has advanced permission to a role and lookup the service account owner
- lookup over usage pattern of executed queries (might be actually more consumers than producers)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

1. Populate the role’s comment field with the relevant Data Steward information
2. Use Tags (in public preview)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I clarified that I was looking for an automatic/scalable approach

Comment: Ok - so what is your definition of a “data steward” for a role?